# Z-fighting solutions in depth test in OpenGL - how do they work?

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, glsl, shader

### **Description**

I've had major problems with Z-Fighting in OpenGL and I've spent quite some time finding solutions for this problem. Some of the ones I've found and I understand and didn't like:

- Moving polygons away from each other ( like glPolygonOffset in OpenGL )
- Dividing the scene according to Z coordinate and drawing parts of the scene with separate clean z-buffers.

The ones I don't understand:

- Using Projection Matrix 
  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/alternatives-to-using-z-bias-to-fix-z-fighting-issues
- Using "Logarithmic Depth Buffers" 
  http://outerra.blogspot.com/2012/11/maximizing-depth-buffer-range-and.html

I've implemented the second one in my program by just puting this into the vertex shader of a ball (it z-fought with the ground) :

```
float C = 1.0; 
float far = 2000.0; 
   gl_Position = u_projView * a_position;      
gl_Position.z = 2.0*log(gl_Position.w*C + 1.0)/log(far*C + 1.0) - 1.0;
gl_Position.z *= gl_Position.w;
```

and it worked!

### **Actual Questions**

1. Can anyone explain me how did changing the Z coordinate of the vertex in the vertex shader solved the problem WITHOUT moving the vertex visibly to me ? (the scene looks the same to the human eye). How did it change the distribution of the z-depth values ? I'm guessing i'm missing some knowledge about rendering pipeline.
2. Can anyone explain to me how can we use **Projection Matrix** to fix the problem ? And how does it work?
3. Are there any other similarly effective ways to fixing z-fighting problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I figure your scene really has a very large range of z-values that need to be rendered? How large is the range?

Comment: Near plane is 1.0 and far plane is 2000

Comment: I should probably elaborate: the only way that changing the value of `z` is ever going to change what appears on screen (aside from depth fighting) is if it is done in or before ***eye-space***, because that is what `w` is derived from for perspective projection (`-eye.z`). It is not done in eye-space in this example, but rather clip-space (which comes after eye-space), so the value of `z` does not change `x` or `y`. The output image is 2D, if neither `x` nor `y` changes, you will not ***see*** any difference in geometry on your screen.

Comment: @MikeWazowsky: Well the article you linked already explains the method you implemented in great detail. It also explains why just changing the vertex shader the way you did does _not_ work in the general case. You need to adjust the calculated depth value per fragment, too, otherwise you can get the case where primitives which appear relatively large in screen space might be wrongly intersected with other geometry close by.

Comment: @MikeWazowsky: the method with the projection matrix is use _more than one_ projection matrix (a one for near objects, another one for far ones) when rendering the scene. This is quite an hack and works only well for a certain types of scenes. And it also is explained in the links you gave.

Comment: `when z fighting appears, push the z near plane you will.` simple buddhist knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's a problem with depth buffer precision? When using 16-bit buffer, z-fighting is likely to happen. You can check it using:

```
glGetIntegerv( GL_DEPTH_BITS, &depthBits);
```