# Drawing the grid over the texture

Tags: opengl, jogl

Before diving into details, I have added [opengl](/questions/tagged/opengl) tag because JoGL is a Java OpenGL binding and the questions seem to be accessible for experts of both to answer.

Basically what I am trying to do is to render the grid over the texture in JoGL using GLSL. So far, my idea was to render first the texture and draw the grid on top. So what I am doing is:

```
gl2.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
// skipped the code where I setup the model-view matrix and where I do fill the buffers
gl2.glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttrId, 3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer.rewind());
gl2.glVertexAttribPointer(textureAttrId, 2, GL2.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, textureBuffer.rewind());
gl2.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffer.rewind());
```

And after I draw the grid, using:

```
gl2.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
gl2.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_LINE_STRIP, indices, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffer.rewind());
```

Without enabling the depth test, the result look pretty awesome.
[image: no depth test]

But when I start updating the coordinates of the vertices (namely updating one of its axes which corresponds to height), the rendering is done in a wrong way (some things which should be in front appear behind, which makes sense without the depth test enabled). So I have enabled the depth test:

```
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
gl.glDepthMask(true);
```

An the result of the rendering is the following:
[image]

You can clearly see that the lines of the grid are blured, some of the are displayed thinner then others, etc. What I have tried to do to fix the problem is some line smoothing:

```
gl2.glHint(GL2.GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
```

The result is better, but I am not still satisfied.

[image]

**QUESTION**: So basically the question is how to improve further the solution, so I can see solid lines and those are displayed nicely when I start updating the vertex coordinates.

If it is required I can provide the code of Shaders (which is really simple, Vertex Shader only calculates the position based on projection, model view matrix and the vertex coords and Fragment Shader calculates the color from texture sampler).

Comment: What you are witnessing is called [z-figthing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). You can look http://stackoverflow.com/q/24142068/2293156 for possible solutions

Comment: @Amadeus cheerz, thank you got input. Actually the solution which the author of the question has mentioned (I have implemented http://outerra.blogspot.ch/2012/11/maximizing-depth-buffer-range-and.html) are solving the problem. Thanks a lot (maybe you could elaborate a fast answer, so I could award you some rep?)